# If statement- Differences - python 2x

Tags: python-2.7, if-statement, for-loop

I don't understand the difference between the two codes:

```
grade = [100, 97, 73, 56, 78,34]
for i in range(len(grade)):
    if grade[i]%2 == 0:
        grade[i]= grade[i]+2
    elif grade[i]%3 ==0:
        grade[i]= grade[i]+3
    elif grade[i]%5 ==0:
        grade[i]= grade[i]+5
```

second code:

```
 for i in range(0,len(grade)):
     if grade[i]%2 == 0:
        grade[i]= grade[i]+2
            if grade[i]%3 ==0:
                grade[i]= grade[i]+3  
                if grade[i]%5 ==0:
                    grade[i]= grade[i]+5
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first one will evaluate every statement in the if/elif blocks in the second one each statement will be evaluated only if the previous one pass (is True).

Also, in the first one grade will be modified just in the case of one block is true so for 100 it will modify grade in the first block, not going inside the other blocks, if a number is divisible by 2, 3 and 5 it will just be modified by the first block, and so on. In the second one if a number is divisible by 2,3 and 5 grade will modify it 3 times, once for each block.